# R suppress startupMessages from dependency

Tags: r

One of my R package's dependencies displays startup messages when loaded.  I would like to suppress these startup messages.

The only fix I found so far was removing the offending package from the Depends: line in my DESCRIPTION file.  Then calling `suppressPackageStartupMessages(require("offendingPackage"))`    in `.onLoad` of my package.

I would rather keep the offending package as part of my Depends, but it seems that anything specified in depends is automatically loaded and therefore can't be supressed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you work with namespaces, you can specify the package in `Imports`, and load the necessary functions using `import` or `importFrom`. This way, the package is not attached, but the necessary functions can be loaded and used by your package. Without attaching, the startup messages are not given, so this approach assures you won't see any startup messages of packages specified in Imports.

Make sure you check that you imported everything that is of importance. If the package you import is dependent on other packages, I'm not sure everything you need to use those functions is imported. You might have to do a bit of puzzling to get everything you need loaded. On the plus side, using `Imports` assures that any dependencies check will be carried out correctly.

Another option is to not specify the package in `Depends`, but in `Suggests` in the DESCRIPTION file, and use the option @Dirk gave you. This will give a correct dependency check if 'dependencies=TRUE' is set in `install.packages()`. But personally I think using the namespaces is a lot more clean.

Answer (score 46):

The `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` function works if and only if the startup messages are actually written with `packageStartupMessage()` -- see the help page.

Many packages just use `cat()`, which one could consider a buglet.  In that case

```
 suppressMessages(library(foo))
```

works better.

Comment: The offending package does use packageStatupMessage.  I am just looking for a fix that doesn't require me to take the offending package out of my Depends since it causes a warning when calling R CMD check.

Comment: @Nick using Imports and namespaces doesn't result in warnings, and allows you to take the offending package out of Depends.

Comment: I need something even stronger > suppressMessages(library(lasso2))
R Package to solve regression problems while imposing
  an L1 constraint on the parameters. Based on S-plus Release 2.1
Copyright (C) 1998, 1999
Justin Lokhorst   <jlokhors@stats.adelaide.edu.au>
Berwin A. Turlach <bturlach@stats.adelaide.edu.au>
Bill Venables     <wvenable@stats.adelaide.edu.au>

Copyright (C) 2002
Martin Maechler <maechler@stat.math.ethz.ch>

Comment: Well ... in cases like this, and for local use, I have in the past simply downloaded the code and commented out the message. Won't help you for customer sites which install from CRAN though.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack to do this inline in a script or environment is to override `library()/require()` to wrap the `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` method:

```
> library(here) # This shows a message
here() starts at /home/z/development/
```

```
> require(here) # This shows a message
Loading required package: here
here() starts at /home/y
```

The workaround:

```
> flibrary <- library
> library <- function(...) suppressPackageStartupMessages(flibrary(...))
> library(here) # No messages
>
```

```
> frequire <- require
> require <- function(...) suppressPackageStartupMessages(frequire(...))
> require(here) # No messages
>
```