# Silencing a package load message in Sweave

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I'm loading `optmatch` in a Sweave document as follows:

```
<<myCodeBlock, echo=FALSE>>=
library(optmatch, quietly=TRUE)
@

You're loading optmatch, by Ben Hansen, a package for flexible
and optimal matching. Important license information:
The optmatch package makes essential use of D. P. Bertsekas
and P. Tseng's RELAX-IV algorithm and code, as well as
Bertsekas' AUCTION algorithm and code.
Bertsekas and Tseng freely permit their software to be used for
research purposes, but non-research uses, including the use of it
to 'satisfy in any part commercial delivery requirements to
government or industry,' require a special agreement with them.
By extension, this requirement applies to any use of the
fullmatch() function. (If you are using another package that has
loaded optmatch, then you will probably be using fullmatch indirectly.)
For more information, enter relaxinfo() at the command line
```

As you can see, I've tried every way I can think of to silence the package load message, to no avail.  I assume this is because they just used a straight-up `cat()` or something like that, but it's mighty annoying.  Any thoughts on how to silence this so that those reading my final, beautiful, `LaTeX`ified PDF don't have to read about RELAX-IV?

Other things that don't seem to work (take from Andrie's pointer to a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency)):

```
suppressMessages(library(optmatch))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require("optmatch"))
```

I should note this is pretty obviously an R problem not a Sweave problem, as the messages pop up in R also.

Comment: I believe this question has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6279808/602276

Comment: Thanks!  Super helpful.  But neither of those works either, amazingly enough.  Thought for sure `suppressMessages` would.

Comment: I suggest you contact the author(s) on this kind of non-standard startup messages; `cat()` should be avoided in `.onLoad()`. The standard practice should be `packageStartupMessage()`, which can be suppressed by `suppressPackageStartupMessages()`; for `cat()`, we have to use all sorts of dirty tricks to hide the messages.

Comment: Re-tagging with [tag:knitr], since the solutions I've tested appear to work identically across both `Sweave` and `knitr`.

Comment: See my rant "watch out your cats" here: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/ :)

Comment: @Yihui I actually found that post and tried `echo=FALSE,results='hide',messages=FALSE` before I came here today.  `xtable` was not amenable, but it yielded to `suppressMessages()`.  But I'd forgotten that I'd quoted the `hide` part :-)

Comment: @AriB.Friedman interesting... if you want to kill everything, you can simply `include=FALSE`

Comment: @Yihui Excellent.  I usually have a load packages block at the top of my document, so `include=FALSE` looks perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try loading the package in a hide results chunk:

```
<<packages,results=hide>>= 
require(optmatch) 
@
```

If you use the `knitr` package, you need to [quote `hide`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options):

```
<<packages,results='hide'>>= 
require(optmatch) 
@
```

Comment: That did it.  Turned it the answer was Sweave-specific after all!

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Just added the knitr solution below; the only difference is `hide` vs `'hide'`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an R solution to your problem.  The package author uses `cat` to print the messages to the console, rather than using standard message statements.  You can intercept these messages by using `sink` to divert console output to a temporary file:

```
<<myCodeBlock, echo=FALSE>>=
zz <- tempfile()
sink(file=zz)
library(optmatch, quietly=TRUE))
unlink(zz)
@
```

---

PS. The solution by `@XuWang` uses only SWeave, so is clearly much more suitable in your case.

Comment: or `invisible(capture.output(library(optmatch, quietly=TRUE)))`