# knitr shows comments from library import

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I have a small Rnw file. When compiled with knitr, it shows importing comments in the pdf. How do I remove these comments? Here is the file a.Rnw:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Hi, this is an example!
<<setup, echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE>>==
library(earth, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
a <- rnorm(100); b<- 0.05*rnorm(100) - .2*a
model <- lm(a~b)
plot(model)
@
\end{document}
```

When I compile with knitr

```
$ Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('a.Rnw')"
```

I get this extraneous bit in the tex file:

```
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
{\ttfamily\noindent\itshape\color{messagecolor}{\#\# Loading required package: plotmo\\\#\# Loading required package: plotrix}}\end{kframe}
```

Which shows up as 
[image]

Is this normal? How do I remove these comments?

Comment: many options to deal with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143332/silencing-a-package-load-message-in-sweave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to put `message=FALSE` in your chunk options, either locally for that chunk or via `library(knitr); opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE)` near the head of your document.

This is a little bit simpler than the question that [@rawr links to in the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143332/silencing-a-package-load-message-in-sweave), because that referred to a badly behaved package that used `cat()` rather than `message()` for its startup messages.  `message=FALSE` will suppress *all* messages produced by the chunk; if you want to be a little bit more precise

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(earth))
```

should work, but I find that `message=FALSE` is usually harmless enough, and looks prettier (e.g. if you wanted `echo=TRUE` instead).