# Suppress other packages' startup messages OR fix my imports

Tags: r, import, dependencies, message

I am about to release an R package, but I am having trouble with the messages that are printed to the R console when the package is loaded in R. My package depends on several other packages, and these other packages display various welcome and startup messages. This is because I added the packages to the `Depends` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file rather than the `Imports` field. My understanding is that using the `Imports` field would suppress the startup messages. However, if I import the packages rather than depend on them, my examples in the help files no longer work because some functions in these packages, which are used by other functions in the same packages which are in turn used by functions I am using in my package code, cannot be found. What can I do to suppress the dozens of lines of messages without importing them (that is, by having them in the `Depends` field)? Or, alternatively, how can I make sure the functions are all available when I import them? Does the problem occur because the functions which are indirectly needed are not exported by the package in question? It does not seem to work even if I import the problematic functions explicitly...

**Edit - more details:** A function in my package calls the `ergmMPLE()` function in the `ergm` package. So I have added `Imports: ergm` to the `DESCRIPTION` file and `import("ergm")` to the `NAMESPACE` file. When I use the function in my package, I get an error message that the function `check.control.class` could not be found by the `ergmMPLE` function. So I looked up this function and it appears to be located in yet another package called `statnet.common`. Therefore I added `statnet.common` to the `Imports` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file as well and added `import("statnet.common")` to the `NAMESPACE` file. Now it looks like the `ergmMPLE` function still does not find the `check.control.class` function. My solution would be to just let my package depend on the `statnet.common` package, but then I have the problem with the startup messages again...

Answer (score 1):

You can put the packages in the `Import` part and load the necessary functions from the other packages using `import` or `importForm`. For more details see:

- [R suppress startupMessages from dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency)

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done, but when I use the functions in my package, R still complains that the function called by the other function called by my package code could not be found.

Comment: I have added more details to my question above. Perhaps this helps to understand the problem better. Thanks.