# Rscript in silent mode

Tags: r, rscript

I am using Rscript to run an R script but I get a lot of output on my screen. Can I run Rscript in silent mode (meaning without any screen output)?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I know that Octave can be called with a --quiet option. I wonder if there is something similar in R.

Comment: Sure it can, try `R --help`, but that only affects R itself.  But there is also `--slave` ....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Several options come to mind:

1. within R: use `sink()` to divert output to a file, see `help(sink)`
2. on the shell:  `Rscript myscript.R 2>&1 >/dev/null`
3. edit the code :)
4. on Linux, use our [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) frontend as it runs in `--slave` mode by default :)

Options 3 is the most involved but possibly best.  You could use a logging scheme where you print / display in "debug" or "verbose" but not otherwise.  I often do that, based on a command-line toggle given to the script.

Comment: Funny. I tried your options and they more or less worked. Some things were not hidden though. I am using the Amelia II package and its information (like version and copyright) are still being displayed even after using sink and/or 2>&1 >/dev/null...

Comment: Feel free to accept or upvote then.  Package startup messages are different, and there are some questions here explaining the details, see eg [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency). You can nuke those by wrapping `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` around your `library()` call; I often just use `suppressMessages()`.

Comment: Option 2 has the output redirection reversed, [see here](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/13w/notes/200_redirection.html#redirecting-both-stdout-and-stderr-using-21). If you test with `Rscript -e "library(tidyverse)" 2>&1> /dev/null` you still see output, but it is all silenced with `Rscript -e "library(tidyverse)" > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 6):

You can redirect the output with

```
Rscript myscript.R >& >/dev/null (linux)
```

or

```
Rscript myscript.R >$null (windows)
```

or use `R` directly:

```
R --quiet --vanilla < myscript.R
```

or

```
R CMD BATCH myscript.R
```

(That last version writes the output to a file `myscript.Rout`)

Comment: I think I can't use R directly because I am expecting some arguments from the command line...

Answer (score 0):

One more option: if you want to separate the output and the error message into different files, which makes it easier to identify the problems, you can use the command on the shell:

```
Rscript myscript.R >a.Rout 2>a.Rerr
```

This will write the program output to a.Rout and the error messages to a.Rerr. Note that the files of a.Rout and a.Rerr should be removed beforehand, to avoid an error.