# Knitr Markdown - Sourced Script returns empty lists + ugly source file output

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I'm trying on a simple knitr markdown "exercise". What I want to do is to simply source my R script file and output some of the data, e.g. the mean of a vector.

My code

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
summary(cars)
source("GETPrices.R")

x  <- BooliReq()
mean(x$sold$listPrice)

```
````

Firstly, the `source ("GETPrices.R")` generates an ugly

> ### Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
>
> ### The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
>
> ### View

in the output file. How can this be prevented?

Secondly, when I e.g. try to output the mean value (see code above), all I get is

> ### Warning in mean.default(x$sold$listPrice): argument is not numeric or
>
> ### logical: returning NA

Outputting the mean in this way works fine though in console. So what is the issue?

Comment: For starters see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723034/howto-suppress-one-commands-output-in-r http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, use the options:

```
{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
```