# How to prevent modeest from printing a startup message whether loaded or not?

Tags: r

When I run R (even as a headless Rscript loading zero libraries) I occasionally see

```
This is package 'modeest' written by P. PONCET.
For a complete list of functions, use 'library(help = "modeest")' or 'help.start()'.
```

It's polluting output of my log files. While I find it useful for a few things, I rarely load it. How can I prevent it from spewing messages in this case? I know if I actually load a library I can `suppressPackageStartupMessages`, but this message appears even without loading any packages.

It could be that I every time I see this I am calling a function that is part of a package that has a dependency on a package which has a dependency on `modeest` (at least somewhere in the daisy chain), even if I don't use `library(...)`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. install modeest package
2. write a package with a function that imports a function from modeest
3. write another package with a function that depends on an unrelated (to modeest) function in the package mentioned in step 2
4. call a function from the package from step 3 either with `package::func(arg)` or `library(package); func(arg)` that doesn't depend on `modeest` anywhere.

Comment: Maybe some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681688/disable-messages-upon-loading-package-in-r. A [reproduicble example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful to really solving your problem.

Comment: The first stackoverflow question you link to is closer to the mark. However, the solution says to use `importFrom`. I do that exclusively for all my packages.

Comment: Okay, checked again: The author seems to recognise the problem [according to an explanatory comment](https://github.com/paulponcet/modeest/blob/7d0e1d36ce17bc051257bcd8c45e44a8d320d790/R/zzz.R#L10) … and then does nothing about it. So, I’ll go back to my initial assessment: shout at the author (= file a bug report), this is bad behaviour and should be fixed in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; the behaviour is caused by the fact that `packageStartupMessage` is called in the wrong package hook.

This is a bug. [I’ve submitted a pull request](https://github.com/paulponcet/modeest/pull/5) to fix the bug.

Unfortunately short of this fix there isn’t much that can be done to avoid this. — One thing would be to hotpatch `base::packageStartupMessage` before loading any other packages via `assignInNamespace`. This should really be a last resort though.