# Suppress start-up messages when loading a library to snowfall cluster with sfLibrary

Tags: r, raster, snow, snowfall

Example of the code I am running below.

```r
library(snowfall)
library(snow)

sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 3)

sfLibrary(raster)
```

```r
Library raster loaded.
Library raster loaded in cluster.
```

I want to stop sfLibrary from printing the messages. I can't figure out how. Help please...

Thanks.

EDIT 1: This does not work:

suppressMessages(sfLibrary(raster))

Library raster loaded.

EDIT 2: This does not work:

suppressPackageStartupMessages(sfLibrary(raster))

Library raster loaded.

Library raster loaded in cluster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R suppress startupMessages from dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please see above edits to my question. Those options don't seem to work with sfLibrary() .

Comment: Try `capture.output` in combination with the other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Use the Source.*

If you look at the source code for `sfLibrary`, specifically where it [prints those messages](https://github.com/cran/snowfall/blob/master/R/clusterFunctions.R#L123-L126), you'll see that is uses `sfCat`. Tracing that down ([same file](https://github.com/cran/snowfall/blob/master/R/clusterFunctions.R#L591)), it uses `cat`.

I know of two ways to prevent `cat` from dumping onto the console: `capture.output` and `sink`.

1. [`capture.output`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/capture.output.html): *"evaluates its arguments with the output being returned as a character string or sent to a file"*.

   ```r
   cat("quux4\n")
   # quux4
   invisible(capture.output(cat("quux5\n")))
   cat("quux6\n")
   # quux6
   ```

   Since `capture.output` returns the captured output *visibly* as a `character` vector, wrapping it in `invisible` or storing the return value into a variable (that is ignored and/or removed) will prevent its output on the console.
2. [`sink`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html): *"send R output to a file"*.

   ```r
   cat("quux1\n")
   # quux1
   sink("ignore_me.txt")
   cat("quux2\n")
   sink(NULL) # remove the sink
   cat("quux3\n")
   # quux3
   ```

I personally find the use of `sink` (in general) to be with some risks, especially in automation. One good example is that `knitr` uses `sink` when capturing the output for code chunks; nested calls to `sink` have issues. An astute reader will notice that `capture.output` [uses `sink`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/utils/R/capture.output.R#L35), so neither is better in that regard.

Looking again at the source (first link above),

```
else {
  ## Load message in slave logs.
  sfCat( paste( "Library", .sfPars$package, "loaded.\n" ) )

  ## Message in masterlog.
  message( paste( "Library", .sfPars$package, "loaded in cluster.\n" ) )
}
```

you'll see that it also calls `message`, which is *not* caught by `capture.output` by default. You can always use `capture.output(..., type="message")`, but then you aren't capturing the `cat` output as well. So you are left with having to capture both types, either with nested `capture.output` or with [`suppressMessages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/message.html).

I suggest you can either use `suppressMessages(invisible(capture.output(sfLibrary(raster))))` or write some helper function that does that for you.

Comment: Nice investigative work! Your final suggestion works well.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.