# warning message for data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with Rstudio, when I am trying to call data.table in R

```
Library (data.table)
```

I revived the following warning  message

```
data.table 1.14.0 using 4 threads (see ?getdtthreads). Latset news r-datatable.com
```

I have updated my R and Rstudio t the latest version, then I removed the package completely, and installed it again

```
remove.packages("data.table")
install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
    repos = "https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table")
```

however, the message is still existed

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

Comment: why don't you install it directly from cran repo ?

Comment: What's not a warning message. It's just informational. It's just telling you how many threads it's using by default. If you want to suppress all messages, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency

Comment: I wonder, is the problem you see here that you are trying to install version 1.14.2, yet the message tells you that only 1.14.0 is install? If so, then it seems likely that you need to look for other installations of `data.table`: check directories in `.libPaths()`; they are used in order, so if your personal package/library is last, then any directory before it that contains a different version of the package will be used instead.